# render page after submission of a form in ror

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form from which i select college_ids.when i select college_id, a query is executed and that result is sent to other form of different method.i want to display  those two forms in single page.

Here is my form

```
<%= form_tag(student_index_path, :method=>'get') do %>

 <p>
 College <br />
<%= select("get", "clg", College.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>
</p>


<p>
  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
</p>


<% end %>
```

Here is my student html

```
<%= form_tag(result_index_path, :method=>'get') do %>

<p>
 Year <br />
 <%= select("get", "stu", @students.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>
</p>


<p>
 <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

in my controller:

```
 def college
 end

 def student
           @students = Student.where(:college_id => params[:get][:clg])
  end
 def result
   @res = Data.where(:id => params[:get][:stu])  
 end
```

in my result_path i am getting details from Data table.

This code is working.I am trying to display college and student form in same page.what should i do..

I have tried it using ajax but the second form i.e student's form is dependent on college form.so the select tag i.e <%= select("get", "stu", @students.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>  have @students that is defined in college method.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution to this problem is as follows:

1)Make partial for student form i.e _student_form.html.erb

2) Display partial on same page after person select college using ajax. Initially make

`<div id="StudentForm"></div>`

Keep it empty. Make college form ajaxed, and then submission of college form would add student form of above partial to the same page.

Changes to action where college form is submitted would to collect college id and get student of that college.